# Excel VBA Function updates cell contents as desired in VBA Window, but not in Excel workbook view

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a series of functions to use the VBA-tools/VBA-Web add-in to pull from my server's APIs.  It's a rather complex series of functions, contained in one Workbook module and calling the VBA-Web functions.

I'm storing some of the variables - the API security information and server url - in the Sheet1 spreadsheet (I'll probably call it something different later on) so that if I shared this with other users, they could customize for their server.

All is working well if run in the VBA development environment window in Excel, but if I try to call the function by inserting it in a cell, e.g. =SierraAWSResponse("i","9780399207495"), it seems to stop at updating a value in the workbook, if I can believe my debug statements.
Here's the code around where it stops:

```
Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)
If Response.StatusCode = 200 Then
  rsp = CStr(Response.Data("access_token"))
  If WebHelpers.EnableLogging Then Debug.Print "Code = 200 -->  " & rsp
  ThisWorkbook.Names("token").RefersToRange(1, 1).Value = rsp
  If WebHelpers.EnableLogging Then Debug.Print "assign getSierraToken"
End If
```

It writes that "Code = 200 --> " & rsp line, but never updates "ThisWorkbook.Names("token")...

Is it something about my not having End If's on the debug statements?  I could test that, I guess...  But it's working in the code view window.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: A function called from a worksheet as a UDF can only return a value (or array of values) to the calling cell(s).  It can't have "side effects" like updating some other cell or range.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: Consider a push button run sub. It will likely be less expensive in terms of calls as well.